# How do I make Emacs start without so much fanfare?

Tags: emacs

Every time I start Emacs I see a page of help text and a bunch of messages suggesting that I try the tutorial.  How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: Alternatively (if you believe the information displayed might still be useful to you, but want to be able to get rid of it quickly), note that typing `q` will kill that buffer.

Comment: Any update for emacs 27.1? Apparently none of the answers below work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put the following in your `.emacs`:

```
(setq inhibit-startup-message t)
(setq inhibit-startup-echo-area-message t)
```

Answer (score 22):

Emacs has a couple of variables which inhibit these actions.  If you edit your emacs control file (.emacs) and insert the following:

```
;; inhibit-startup-echo-area-message MUST be set to a hardcoded 
;; string of your login name 
(setq inhibit-startup-echo-area-message "USERNAME")
(setq inhibit-startup-message t)
```

that should solve your problem.  They basically set the inhibit parameters to true to prevent the behavior you want to get rid of.

Comment: Do `M-x describe-variable` and enter `user-login-name`; pass whatever is shown as arg. to the function as constant string. Say if it shows `JoeCoder` then in `.emacs` call `(setq inhibit-startup-echo-area-message "JoeCoder")` additionally put `(setq inhibit-startup-message t)`. Oh, also it works only when the former `setq` is independant i.e. no other symbols should be set in this call; see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html#index-inhibit_002dstartup_002decho_002darea_002dmessage) for the reason.

Answer (score 3):

You can customize message in minibuffer therefore remove fanfare:

```
;; Hide advertisement from minibuffer
(defun display-startup-echo-area-message ()
  (message ""))
```

Comment: Your example is good for users who wish to put a *different* message.  If a user just wishes to suppress the message entirely, the following could be used:  `(defun display-startup-echo-area-message () )`

Answer (score 2):

Put the following in your personal init file (ususally `~/.emacs.el`):

```
(setq inhibit-startup-message t)
```

(Or `(setq inhibit-startup-screen t)` in with older Emacs versions.)

You can also turn off the message "For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a." in the echo with the variable `inhibit-startup-echo-area-message`, but it is not enough to set it to `t`; you must set it to your username.  See the documentation for `inhibit-startup-echo-area-message`.

Comment: Yeah, not even `(setq inhibit-startup-echo-area-message (user-login-name))` works, ffs.

Comment: @VebjornLjosa: When I put my name there, it gets away with the GNU standard message but instead I get a three-line message: "#[nil "\300C\207" [t] 2]"

Comment: @EmanuelBerg, yes those three lines are whatever is left in the buffer from before (i.e., the last entry in the `*Messages*` buffer).

Comment: Alright, but then it is not meaningful to use the fix as that cryptic message is three-lines, and even more annoying than the GNU one. Or did you find a way to circumvent this, possibly by appending a blank line to the *Messages* buffer?

Comment: @EmanuelBerg: Doing `(delete-minibuffer-contents)` in `.emacs.el` may not help because the message you see may be produced in one of the hooks that run later. See http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html.

Comment: Got it, `(setq inhibit-startup-echo-area-message (lambda ()
                                          (user-login-name)))`

`(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook (lambda ()
                                     (message "Custom message")))`

Comment: @trojanfoe See my comment on paxdiablo's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your init file is byte-compiled, use the following form instead:

```
(eval '(setq inhibit-startup-echo-area-message "YOUR-USER-NAME"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below to your init file

```
(setq inhibit-startup-message t
inhibit-startup-echo-area-message t)
```