# What is in your .emacs file?

Tags: emacs, elisp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's in your .emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154097/whats-in-your-emacs)

I've started to use Emacs and I've been looking up ways to improve my .emacs file. Some of the stuff goes over my head.

But what I wanted to know is what is in your .emacs file that your couldn't go without.

Comment: ahky. I didn't see that question when I was searching. If anyone can close this. Please do.

Comment: says I can't. To many answers and upvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find my .emacs at [github](http://github.com/alexott/emacs-configs/tree/master), all settings are split into separate files (for different programming languages, etc.), located in rc subdirectory

Answer (score 5):

```
(setq visible-bell t)
```

Nothing irritates me more than that god forsaken beep.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest [Steve Yegge's .emacs](http://steve.yegge.googlepages.com/my-dot-emacs-file) file with [his emacs article](http://steve.yegge.googlepages.com/effective-emacs).

Comment: Steve Yegge is the reason I got into emacs :)

Answer (score 2):

Answering your question tangentially, there is one thing that I try *not* to put in my `.emacs`; UI settings.  The reason is that usually, these things can be done in your `.Xresources` file (or Windows registry), which saves quite a bit of time starting up emacs.

Want to disable the tool/menu bar?  Set the default fonts?  Use a [colour theme](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorTheme#toc20)?  All things that can be set as X resources.

Comment: This is a cool answer. I do have some UI settings in my .emacs and it is annoying how it visibly changed on start up.

Comment: How often do you restart emacs?

Answer (score 1):

Steve Yegge's  is my favourite.

And also check this link.
http://www.dotemacs.de/

Answer (score 0):

You may try to my one:
http://github.com/crible/emacs