# How do I open http://localhost in my web browser from Vim?

Tags: vim, localhost

Basically, I want to tell Vim:

1. Open my web browser (for instance, Firefox)
2. Open this file (say index.php) in thought this address : http://localhost
3. In other words: http://localhost/index.php

PS: Unfortunately I use Windows XP

Comment: Basically Vim is an Editor, you have to write a shell script to do that I think. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are running Vim on windows, then this will work:

```
:! start http://localhost/index.php
```

This will use the default browser, if you wanted to start a specific browser then you would need the explicit path to the executable (instead of start).

From the Vim *help cmd*:

> :!{cmd}
>
> Execute {cmd} with the
>   shell.  See also the 'shell'          and
>   'shelltype' option.

Obviously, if you are on some other system you just need to use the appopriate command to start the browser on that platform.

Comment: thanks it worked: start "http://localhost/index.php" "file:///"%:p" (opened my current file in localhost)

Answer (score 7):

on mac you can

```
:!open http://localhost/index.php
```

Answer (score 2):

On Unix/Linux, use

```
:! firefox http://localhost/%:p
```

%:p is the path and filename of the current buffer

Comment: Will this open in the current Firefox instance if one is already open?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a method appropriate to your environment to start the web browser, [but you already asked a question about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035678/how-to-open-files-in-web-browsers-e-g-firefox-within-editors-like-vim-or-emacs).

So, use `:!start cmd /c ...`, `!d:\path\to\firefox ...` or whatever. The important bit: you'll want to use `"http://localhost/" . expand("%:t")` as the argument passed to the browser. So, do something like

```
:exec ":!start cmd /c ... " . "http://localhost/" . expand("%:t")
                         ^- leave a trailing space here
```

**EDIT:** A Clarification: `expand("%:t")` is a Vim script expression which expands to the last component of the current filename. On Windows this means that if the current filename is `C:\a complicated path\to\index.html`, `expand("%:t")` will return `index.html`.

HTH.

Comment: Also, you can use `%:t` in ex commands (the commands which begin with a colon) to signify "the last path component of the file being edited", meaning the basename of the file (like `index.html` in `C:\path\to\index.html`).