# How to open files in web browsers using Firefox, Emacs, Cygwin

Tags: bash, firefox, emacs

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035678/how-to-open-files-in-web-browsers-e-g-firefox-within-editors-like-vim-or-emacs/2051652#2051652) but I have a little problem with the following code (I am using Emacs 24.3 and Cygwin and I don't know Lisp):

```lisp
(defun open-in-browser()
  "Open buffer in browser, unless it is not a file. Then fail silently (ouch)."
  (interactive)
  (if (buffer-file-name)
      (let ((filename (buffer-file-name)))
        (shell-command (concat "start firefox.exe \"file://" filename "\"")))))
```

My `shell-command` is bash. I changed the last line to

```
(shell-command (concat "cygstart d:/program/fox/firefox.exe ...
```

- Opening `d:/documents/test.html` works well.
- Opening `d:/documents/my notes/test.html` does *not* work.
  I get the following error in Firefox:

  > Can not find file `d:/documents/my`

I think bash is missing the space in `my notes`. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> emacs buffer file open ex) d:/documents/test.html ;;work good 
>   emacs buffer file open ex) d:/documents/my notes/test.html ;;not work

It's failing because of the whitespace. You can read a good description of how Bash interprets whitespace here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/108663/84118

Answer (score 0):

In the shell command, change `filename` to `(shell-quote-argument filename)`