# What’s in your .viper file at start-up of Emacs?

Tags: vim, emacs, viper-mode

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154097/whats-in-your-emacs), but for Viper users specifically. How do you customize Viper mode in Emacs?

Answer (score 2):

My .viper:

```
(setq viper-expert-level '5)
(setq viper-inhibit-startup-message 't)
;;; '/' Search ignores case
(setq case-fold-search t)
;;; Can't live without auto-indent in any mode, be it text or source code
(setq-default viper-auto-indent t)
;;; Electrifies Viper
(setq-default viper-electric-mode t)
;;; Useful if you like to bang the ESC key
;; (setq-default viper-no-multiple-ESC t)
;;; This doesn't work for me - YMMV
(setq-default viper-ESC-moves-cursor-back nil)
```

I picked the above customizations from this thread (which has a lot more, though most of is obsolete / redundant when you use Vimpulse) :

http://www.mail-archive.com/implementations-list@lists.ourproject.org/msg00062.html