# Where I can find the most popular Emacs settings?

Tags: emacs, elisp, dot-emacs

While it is fun to customize, the Emacs has 100s of mode and there is lots of customization. I like to find popular choices, so it makes my life easier and I can spend time productively.  It could be about hooks, registers, buffers, keybindings,bookmarks  etc..

If such a thing does not exist, I am still happy to customize in my way.

Comment: go through this one as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154097/whats-in-your-emacs also look into github and such. but idealy, just continue using emacs and anytime you find some feature missing or that you think it can be done in a better way, just look it up in the documentation. the info manuals are pretty extensive in itself.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have a look at the [Emacs Prelude](http://github.com/bbatsov/prelude).

Comment: I think that this is more organized approach for per-mode settings.

Comment: Prelude is a great baseline - honestly I would start with this, and then just build out your `~/.emacs.d/personal/*.el` files as you learn more about Emacs and Emacs Lisp, and so tweak the Prelude baseline to your preferences.

Answer (score 12):

A very popular compilation of popular default settings is the Emacs Starter Kit, originally developed [by Phil Hagelberg](https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit), then by [Eric Schulte](http://eschulte.github.com/emacs-starter-kit/) and finally [updated for emacs-24](https://github.com/eschulte/emacs24-starter-kit). It mentions:

> The main advantage of this Emacs Starter Kit are
>
> - better default settings
> - inclusion of many useful libraries and configurations
> - "literate" customization embedded in Org-mode files
> - an organizational directory structure
> - git provides for version control, backup, and sharing

Then there are some specialized extensions of it:

- the [starter kit for social sciences](http://www.kieranhealy.org/blog/archives/2011/01/11/emacs-starter-kit-for-the-social-sciences-now-easier-to-install/)
- the [emacs kicker](http://tapoueh.org/blog/2011/04/15-emacs-kicker.html)
- the [emacs expert kick](http://kanis.fr/emacs-expert-kit.html)

For most popular "aha" settings, the Emacs NiftyTricks page from the emacs wiki has already been linked to in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028055/where-i-can-find-most-popular-emacs-settings/7028536#7028536).

Answer (score 6):

I don't know a single collection of settings, but [Emacs nifty tricks](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsNiftyTricks) can be a good starting place to pick up useful customizations and features you may not know.

It's not strictly customization, but [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60367/the-single-most-useful-emacs-feature) list useful features of Emacs.

Answer (score 6):

I personally advise:

- [Link](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/emacs_make_modern.html) - how to make Emacs settings compatible with modern conventions
- [Link](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/ergonomic_emacs_keybinding.html) - ergonomic keybinding scheme

There is also [Emacs Prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/emacs-prelude) - a set of customization to make Emacs learning curve more gradual.

I also recommend going through [Mastering Emacs](https://www.masteringemacs.org/) - it has many of customizations, that may improve your productivity.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the starter some time ago, but I found that I got better results by writing my own init.el so that I actually know what each line of cod e does. Emacs Fu is the best resource that I know, because it has blog posts about many different modes instead of just code: http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/. And there is also sample .emacs based on the posts.

Answer (score 0):

I think maintainer of Emacs rocks series ended up with a good `.emacs` settings and a useful start-up-kit for newbies to help them morph their finger habits quickly into Emacs'.
https://github.com/magnars/.emacs.d. The `better-defaults` package lives up to its title.