# How to have Emacs create backup files with OpenVMS Files-11 style file names with version numbers?

Tags: emacs, versioning, openvms

This [SO answer about .emacs file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/845311/101954) contains:

```
;; keep backup files neatly out of the way in .~/
(setq backup-directory-alist '(("." . ".~")))
```

which triggered an idea that it would be handy if Emacs would create backup files using the [OpenVMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVMS) [Files-11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Files-11#Disk_organization_and_naming) version naming. For example, `x.txt;3` or `x.txt.3` for the third version of `x.txt`

Comment: Is that really that much better than just using a VCS?

Comment: @pmr 19 years of Files-11 versioning made me wonder how people on Windows and Unix lived without it. I still find the lack irritating -- that the file systems do not handle versions automagicly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this article: http://www.glindra.org/doc/version_number.html.  The short story is to add:

```
(setq version-control t)
```

in your .emacs file.